# Sharepoint Online Authentication with Play Framework web application (Scala)

Tags: scala, authentication, sharepoint, playframework, azure-active-directory

We are trying to connect our Play framework application with the Sharepoint Online site collection. As per the ADAL libraries these are JAVA based and we are unable to use these libraries in the Play framework (based on Scala language).

What are the options available to connect play framework web app with Azure AD, so we will be able to view sharepoint data over the internet?

How to configure the SharePoint site collection to only allow the access based on a either a user or an IP Address?

Answer (score 1):

The [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) uses REST endpoints so you can access Azure AD resources regardless of what language or framework you are using. The above document has links to the specific Azure AD and SharePoint documents you will need.